# Prettier and ESLint Conflict using airbnb style guide with Comma dangle

Tags: eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

ESLint is generating a warning on line 7 of the below code for a missing trailing comma.
My prettier settings is set to the default of es5. This is creating a conflic. Should I set this to 'all' in prettier settings order to comply with airbnb style guide or is it better to disable this warning in ESLint?

```
 app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'redacted',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }),
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

may i know what is your `.eslintrc.js` settings? did you install `eslint-config-prettier` and add `extends: ["prettier"]` to disable ESLint rules that will conflict with prettier?